# setxkbmap: Multiple layouts with different variants

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

Using `setxkbmap` from a user's `.xinitrc`, I'd like to configure:

- German keyboard layout (`de`) without dead keys (variant `nodeadkeys`).
- French keyboard layout (`fr`) *with* dead keys (variant `basic`).

So far I only managed to specify the same variant for both:

```
setxkbmap de,fr nodeadkeys
```

*Is it possible to specify different variants?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [xorg](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Config.html) docs and [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg):

> You must specify as many variants as the number of specified layouts.
>   If you want the default variant, specify an empty string as the
>   variant (the comma must stay)

i.e.

```
setxkbmap -layout "L1,L2, ... ,Ln" -variant "V1,V2, ... ,Vn"
```

In your case:

```
setxkbmap -layout "de,fr" -variant "nodeadkeys,basic"
```

Comment: If one of your keyboards doesn't need a variant, put a comma and then leave the value blank `-layout "L1,L2" -variant "V1,"`

Comment: You might want to also set a key to switch between keyboard layouts, such as the two shifts: `setxkbmap -option grp:shifts_toggle`

Comment: Here's the code to switch between qwerty and colemak using the toggle `Alt+Shift`: `setxkbmap -layout "us,us" -variant ",colemak_dh_iso" -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'`